# How to set breakpoint on all functions in a C++ file using VS Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gdb

We can use following gdb command to set breakpoint in all functions in a file:

```
(gdb) rbreak file.cpp:.*
```

Is there a way to achieve the same feature when debugging from VSCode?

Comment: You could just enter that command into the gdb console?

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you are debugging in VS Code using the GDB debugger (and not the Visual Studio Windows Debugger).

> **GDB, LLDB, and LLDB-MI Commands (GDB/LLDB)** For the C++ (GDB/LLDB) debugging environment, you can execute GDB, LLDB and LLDB-MI commands
> directly through the debug console with the -exec command, but be
> careful, executing commands directly in the debug console is untested
> and might crash VS Code in some cases

quoted from https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cpp-debug

as Alan Birtles said in a comment to you question, you should be able to enter the gdb command here

Answer (score 0):

When using the C/C++ extension for debugging, if you want to run a GDB command in the debug console, you have to prefix the "command line" with with "`-exec`". Ex. `rbreak file.cpp:.`.

If you want to make the command run as a setup command, you can use the `setupCommands` property of the launch config. Ex.

```json
"setupCommands": [
    {
        "text": "rbreak file.cpp:.", // or whatever regex you want
        "description": "set breakpoints on all functions in files matching a regular expression",
        // "ignoreFailures": true
    },
],
```

You can find related GDB docs [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html/Set-Breaks.html#:%7E:text=Break%20Conditions.-,rbreak%20regex,-Set%20breakpoints%20on), and related VS Code C/C++ docs [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cpp-debug#_gdb-lldb-and-lldbmi-commands-gdblldb) and [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference#_setupcommands).